# How to redirect old url to new url using .htaccess file in codeigniter?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, url

My Old Url:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/view-college?college_name=Shri%20Ram%20College%20of%20Commerce,%20New%20Delhi%20(commerce)
```

My New Url:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/college/Shri%20Ram%20College%20of%20Commerce,%20New%20Delhi%20(commerce)
```

My .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

# To internally rewrite to .php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

I have converted my core php project into codeigniter. When I search my website on google like mywebsite.com and then click on it I am visit my codeigniter website no doubt but when I click on a particular page it showing me old url and 404 error. So, How can I fix it?Please help me.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

`view-college` to `college` is two different routes. I dont know about your other routes as well. May be you can use Google Web Master to find all 404 for pages and fix one by one.

If you have a pattern for all of your URLs you can follow a slimier pattern like this.

```
Redirect /view-college(.*)$ /college/$1 [R=301,L]
```